# Help regarding Turkish E-Visa?

Tags: turkey, pakistani-citizens, e-visas

I am Pakistani citizen with valid UK visit visa. I am planning to visit **Turkey** with my sister during our trip to the UK.

When I submit a single application with my and my sister's detail, the system gives an error

> "e-visas cannot be issued for a total number of 1 applicant(s)." Do you want to proceed with rest of the applications?

[image]

And when I try to submit application with only my details on that, it proceeds to the payment.

I just wanted to ask can I submit applications for myself and my sister separately or do I need to submit single application only? Please help me as we want to travel together. Will there be any problem if we get separate evisas?

Comment: My bad :( Sorry for that Actually i want to visit "Turkey" for 3 days during my trip to UK with my sister. When i submit single application with mine and my sisters detail the system further says "e-visas cannot be issued for a total number of 1 applicant(s)." Do you want to proceed with rest of the applications?. And when i try to submit application with only my details on that, it proceeds to the payment. I just wanted to ask that can i submit applications for myself and my sister separately or i need to submit single application only. Hope it clarifies now!

Comment: Why would you have a problem filing separate application?

Comment: I don't have any problem. I just wanted to confirm that why they are not accepting single application because they mentioned that if you are travelling with family, you can add upto 10 persons. Now i am sure that here won't be any issue because visa’s are associated with a specific passport, not who you’re travelling with. So, i will submit separate applications now :)

Comment: 1. Make sure that you are on the actual government website. Should be no more than $20, otherwise it's a scam. 2. I think you can get a visa for one person, or for a married couple. Not for two people, so you have to apply twice.

Comment: If both of you can get separate e visas, you will be fine. You and your sister have valid Uk visas, try to get separate e visas.

Comment: @ReddHerring This is the more detailed version of the question. It would have been better to answer this version and close the other one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Qtv Please use the edit functionality to modify your original question, rather than posting a new question with more information. We now have two versions of your question: a vague one that's been answered, and this more precise one that hasn't.